# Segmentation fault on assigning to char*

Tags: c, char, segmentation-fault

So I'm writing this code here and I simply want a function to return a character array and assign it to a variable in main function. Here is the function returning char*

```
char* getString(pid_t pid, long address, long length) 
{ 
    char* str =  (char *)malloc((length+1) * sizeof(char));
    int i =0;

    while (i < length)
    {
        char t = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA,pid,address+i,0); 
        str[i] = t; 
        i++;
    }
    //  str[length] = '\0';
    printf(" Exiting getString %s \n ", str);
    return str;
}
```

And here is what I do in main

```
int main { 
    ... 
    ...  
    char* st = getString(pid, arguments[1], arguments[2]); // causes seg fault 
    // printf("getstring %s\n", getString(pid, arguments[1], arguments[2])); works fine
    // and produces correct output 
    return 1;
}
```

I haven't done much in C lately so maybe I'm missing something, but why does printf works and assigning fails? Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

You commented out the line in your function where you null terminate your string.

The fact that it only segfaults in one case in `main()` is simply luck (undefined behavior); you're calling `printf()` in your function as well.